# Using TFS build definitions on a local machine

Tags: tfs, build

I have created a lightly customized TFS build process template and also appropriate TFS build definition. It builds fine on the TFS build server.

Is there any way I can allow developers to reuse the same build process XAML and definition to do full builds on their local machines? Maybe there is some utility which can be run with TFS build process XAML files?

I really would like to avoid maintaining a separate copy of the build script for full local rebuilds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The build templates can only be run by the TFS build service. Without installing that on each developers machine, that might not be the best idea.

An alternative is to setup a share on the developments machine and grant access to the TFS Build account (the one that **TFSBuildServiceHost.exe** runs on the server as). Then the developer can Queue a build and get the Server to Drop the files onto their machine.

[image: Queue Build]

The downside to this is you need a lot of builds to be run on the Agents.

Comment: What's the downside of running a build agent on the machines of developers who need to run this build?

Comment: @JohnSaunders 1. I'm not sure on the TFS licensing model for that. 2. That could be a lot of build agents. Ensuring they're out of the normal "Pool" *might* be problematic depending on team sizes. 3. More machines in TFS to administer.

Comment: It's probably as broad as it's long actually, both have good and bad points the more I think about it.

Comment: Now my project lead asked if there is any way to create old-style MSBuild projects which could be used locally and also on TFS2010 through the UpgradeTemplate. The problem is - TFS2010 does not support creating legacy TFSBuild.proj projects. Uhh, Microsoft, where's reusability?